# safari displays javascript source instead of executing

Tags: javascript, flash, safari, mootools

i have a web application that has javscript interspersed through the page. What happens is that safari will dump the source of the javascript code instead of executing it.  I can reproduce this consistently.

The page is a mashup of different forms of content:

it loads flash videos using osflv and is generated via a php script on the server side.  In addition the page also contains calls to Google Map's API to display a map.  The content is placed in separate tabs using javascript to provide tab interaction.

I am also using mootools, and not sure if that is potentially causing issues.

Here are the javascript includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mootools-1.2.1-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sifr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sifr-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/autocompleter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/observer.js"></script>
<script charset='ISO-8859-1' src='/js/rac.js' language='javascript'></script>
```

rac.js comes from osflv, common.js and alerts.js are custom javascript code that includes custom classes and functions used to either display or manipulate data in the page.

This block of code executes in the page just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var whitney = { src: '/flash/whitney.swf'};
        sIFR.activate(whitney); 
        sIFR.replace(whitney, { selector: 'h6#propertyHeadline', wmode:'transparent',css: {'.sIFR-root': {'color': '#1ca9b9' }}});  
 </script>
```

This code also executes just fine:

```
<script language='javascript'>
  var src = '/player';
  if(!DetectFlashVer(9, 0, 0) && DetectFlashVer(8, 0, 0))
   src = 'player8';
  AC_FL_RunContent('codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0', 'width', 520, 'height', 440, 'src', src, 'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',    'id', 'flvPlayer', 'allowFullScreen', 'true', 'movie', src, 'FlashVars','movie=media/orig/4b845109d99d0.flv&fgcolor=0x1CA9B9&bgcolor=0x000000&autoload=off&volume=70');
</script>
```

This is the final snippet of code that is embedded in the html towards the bottom of the page before the end of the body tag, Safari will randomly spit out the src code in the browser at any point beyond the good maps script include:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=googlemapsapikeyblockedout" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

    function InitPropertyDashboardTabs(){
        mytabs = new TabPanel('DashboardTabPanel');
                initializeGallery();
        initializeSiteplan();
        initializeMap('address blocked out');
        }

    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;

    function initializeSiteplan()
    {
        var flashvars = {PropertyId:1,BasePath:'/',wmode:'transparent'};
        var params = {wmode: 'transparent'};
        var attributes = {id: 'SWFSitePlan',name: 'SWFSitePlan'};
        swfobject.embedSWF("/flash/FloorplanViewer/FloorplanViewer.swf", "SiteplanFlash", "915", "500", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    }

    function initializeGallery()
    {
        var  params = {wmode: 'transparent'};..... (more code)
```

This is what the page with the js dump
[image]
<sub>(source: [oxid8.com](http://www.oxid8.com/screen1.jpg))</sub>

this is what the page should look like:
[image]
<sub>(source: [oxid8.com](http://www.oxid8.com/screen2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you point to an example page? What's the result in other browsers?

Comment: Interested in a solution. We have this same issue from time to time on pages that use TinyMCE.

Comment: Unfortunately its a web app behind a firewall so I can't just point you to a public URL.  let me try and add some more deatils in the post

Comment: @jasonbar: Do you also get this problem on pages with Flash, as Mike does? Or only TinyMCE in it? Can you perhaps post a link or source code somewhere of a page that has this problem?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: It only occurs on pages with TinyMCE (and then only when we have multiple instances of it.) I could put the page source in pastebin BUT when I view source in Safari, *the printed javascript code is not there*! Is there anyway to view the currently rendered source?

Comment: @jasonbar: And the page source in another browser (and mark the pieces that are gone in Safari)? You can have a look at Developer Tools (must be explicitly turned on in Safari, IIRC) and see the generated DOM. I don't know if you can print it, but you can always make a screenshot. A screenshot of a malformed page would also be nice. I'll have a look after I get some sleep, now...

Comment: @jasonbar: Last question for now: does it also occur on http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_04.php (multiple instances of TinyMCE here)?

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot, and gee... this is an important thing I forgot to mention is that if I click on the link to get to this page, then the code dump happens, if i force a reload on the page , it renders correctly the second time around.

Comment: @Mike, @Marcel Korpel: Upgrading TinyMCE to the latest version (3.3rc1) in my test environment fixed the issue. TinyMCE was injecting some javascript that bound an event to onload. THAT event was injecting a block of javascript into the page - in a totally random location (inside other tags, on occassion). Perhaps you can test an see if it is broken with the new rc1 they have available?

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't use the `language` attribute, it's [**deprecated**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

The only thing I can see is that you use `application/javascript` instead of `text/javascript` in your HTML (there's a difference between what you specify in your HTML and the MIME-type servers use when sending a Javascript file), but I cannot reproduce any errors on Chromium/Linux with a simple test case like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>dkdkd</title> 
  </head>
  <body> 
    <script type="application/javascript"> 
      var i=0;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Perhaps you can try this, too.)

Just in case: is the script element closed properly? Is all Javascript correct, i.e. does it pass [**JSLint**](http://www.jslint.com/)?

Perhaps you can paste the full source of the HTML page (preferably on something like [**Pastebin**](http://pastebin.org/)), so we can have a closer look.

Comment: @hobodave: thanks for editing, but Firebug says a random server sends a random JS-file as `application/javascript`, without `x-`, which is the recommended way, according to RFC 4329: http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4329

Comment: Are you implying that even javascript embedded inside my html needs to have application/javascript?  I don't believe that is the problem.

Comment: @Mike: No, but you didn't say it was about inline Javascript: that should be added using `<script type="text/javascript">` (and CDATA when using XHTML). But what do other browsers display? And was is Safari on Mac or on Windows? Can you post (a snippet of) the source, so we can see what the problem might be?

Comment: This is Safari on Mac.  Firefox and IE do not exhibit this problem.  I am also able to reproduce this on Chrome which leads me to believe its a webkit problem?

Comment: Try switching the type from "application/javascript" to "text/javascript" as mentioned before. Also try running that script through jslint. Maybe there is something weird that is making Safari choke. Also, what version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Yeah, you might think this is WebKit-related. You may find something in WebKit Bugzilla with a search like https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=javascript+source (or similar).

Comment: i actually changed it to application/javascript after i saw this post, so that is not the issue.   

Simple scenarios do not cause issues, nor do some more of other pages which have plenty of javscript going on.   It seems to be when
there is a mixture of flash and javascript that causes the issue.

Comment: @Mike: I can't find something useful in WebKit Bugzilla. Can you post a screenshot of a malformed page? Also, can you have a look at Developer Tools and see if the DOM is built correctly? And have a look at 'Resources' and see what the response headers are? (Just guessing...)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, would it be possible for me to send you the src code?  I don't want to post it on the open web.. my email is  mwu {at} oxid8 dot com.

Comment: Well i seem to have potentially solved the problem, but I can't tell you why it works.  I moved the offending block of javascript to a different part of the page (higher up in the html) and now it doesn't barf.  The code is all function calls so there are no inline calls going on in that block.  i find this very strange

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll give this a shot. I was having a similar problem on some pages that used TinyMCE (javascript or even parts of my html were being displayed on the page)

MY solution was to upgrade the version of TinyMCE that I was using. v3.3 has an overhauled Webkit handler.

The issue so far as I can tell was that TinyMCE was injecting (poorly) additional blocks of javascript into the page.

This (and a handful of similar blocks) is always injected into <head>

```
<script type="text/javasript" src="http://www.example.com/javascript/rte/langs/en.js" onload="tinemce.dom.ScriptLoader._onLoad(this,'http://www.example.com/javascript/rte/langs/en.js', 0);">
```

Which, when onload fired, injected the following block into a *random* location in the DOM, mangling whatever it was placed on top of.

```
<script type="javascript" src="http://www.example.com/javascript/rte/langs/en.js">
```

The result of that, as seen in the Webkit Developer Tools was to turn

```
<td class="tab" nowrap="">
```

into:

```
<td class="ta<script stype="text=""javascript"" src="http://www.example.com/javascript/rte/langs/en.js"> "b" nowrap=>"
```

Since that's clearly not valid markup the resulting garbage was output.

Upgrading my install of TinyMCE from the previous stable to v3.3rc1 fixed the issue.[TinyMCE Changelog](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/changelog.txt) references a total Webkit overhaul.

edit: By random I really mean random. It inserts the script tag in a different location each time, sometimes breaking content, sometimes not.